# using int.TryParse with Queryable and expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, expression

I am new to Expressions in c#.

Expression code

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "param");
var constant = Expression.Constant(5, typeof(int));
var equal = Expression.Equal(parameter, constant);
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(equal, parameter);
var compiledExpression = lambdaExpression.Compile();
```

Query contains a string value and I want to apply expresion only if the value is convertible to int

```
int test;
query = query.Where(i => int.TryParse(i.Key, out test) && compiledExpression(test));
```

This returns an error saying int.TryParse is not supported.
Any way to solve this?

Comment: What type of object is query?

Comment: It is a Queryable object @SledgeHammer

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message?

Comment: Is `query` a LINQ to SQL query?

Comment: If it is a LINQ to SQL query, then you cannot use a compiled expression.

Comment: Why are you building a dynamic expression? Does it change based on some input? Take a look at [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes it a linq to sql query.
it is a dynamic expression. @YacoubMassad

Comment: Do you need the dynamic expression to run at the database server (via SQL)?

Comment: Yes @YacoubMassad

Comment: Well, `int.TryParse` is not supported. It can't be translated to SQL, not in any expression you wrap it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use out parameters there.

```
1) var v = q.Where(x => x.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
2) use regex instead of All
3) write a simple method that calls Int32.Parse and just returns a bool to hide the out param
```

for #3:

```
    static bool SafeIntParse(string s)
    {
        int n;
        return Int32.TryParse(s, out n);
    }

    var v = q.Where(x => SafeIntParse(x));
```

The SafeIntParse() method is, of course, a separate static method.

EDIT:

for the regex method:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex("^\\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var v = q.Where(x => regex.Match(x).Success);
```

Of course, make the regex object a static object of the class.

Comment: Part (2) is not clear.

I tried (3) but it throws error lambda expressions are not allowed 
@sledgehammer

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. What I meant was can please elaborate Part2 use regex instead of all. Where and how? @sledgehammer

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own function to get the value, ***int.TryParse*** returns 0 by default if the string cannot be converted.

Here you have

```
private decimal GetDecimal(string value)
{
    if(decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal result))
        return result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see the comments. It's a query that should be translated into SQL. Calling `GetDecimal` instead of `int.TryParse` isn't supported either.